# How to add a view/gesture recognisers to iPhone/iPad home Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Until today I believed that it's impossible but there is an app is called **Shou** from the [Emu4iOS Store](http://emu4ios.net/) that record your screen and even if the app is in background there is a view on home screen that on touch redirect you to the app. (please see attached image)[image: ShouScreenShot]

 My Question is how can I achieve the same ? How can I add a view to Home screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a status bar in a recording state. These are system defined states, such as the green bar you get while taking a call. These appear when an app is recording audio automatically, and there is no way to trigger it manually.

There is no way to add views and gesture recognizers on to the springboard.

Comment: can we get this while recoding audio in background in our app?

Comment: @iTroyd23 if you're recording audio in the background, it will only show when the app is not the frontmost app on the phone.

Comment: Yes, i tried that. But i didn't get the redColor status bar While app is recording audio in background. I didnt know what i missed here!!

Comment: @MuruganandhamK is it even recording audio in the background? Check because I dont think your implementation is correct.

Comment: the audio was recorded in background and playing well.

Comment: @MuruganandhamK I don't know then. Try using a different phone.